# Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?

Tags: permissions, directory

If I have a root folder with some restrictive permission, let's say 600, and if the child folders/files have 777 permission will everybody be able to read/write/execute the child file even though the root folder has 600?

Comment: Note that chmodding a directory to 600 makes it unaccessible to even the owner, as you need execute permission to chdir into it...

Answer (score 260, accepted):

The precise rule is: you can traverse a directory if and only if you have execute permission on it.

So for example to access `dir/subdir/file`, you need execute permission on `dir` and `dir/subdir`, plus the permissions on `file` for the type of access you want. Getting into corner cases, I'm not sure whether it's universal that you need execute permission on the current directory to access a file through a relative path (you do on Linux).

The way you access a file matters. For example, if you have execute permissions on `/foo/bar` but not on `/foo`, but your current directory is `/foo/bar`, you can access files in `/foo/bar` through a relative path but not through an absolute path. You can't change to `/foo/bar` in this scenario; a more privileged process has presumably done `cd /foo/bar` before going unprivileged. If a file has multiple hard links, the path you use to access it determines your access constraints.

Symbolic links change nothing. The kernel uses the access rights of the calling process to traverse them. For example, if `sym` is a symbolic link to the directory `dir`, you need execute permission on `dir` to access `sym/foo`. The permissions on the symlink itself may or may not matter depending on the OS and filesystem (some respect them, some ignore them).

Removing execute permission from the root directory effectively restricts a user to a part of the directory tree (which a more privileged process must change into). This requires access control lists to be any use. For example, if `/` and `/home` are off-limits to `joe` (`setfacl -m user:joe:0 / /home`) and `/home/joe` is `joe`'s home directory, then `joe` won't be able to access the rest of the system (including running shell scripts with `/bin/sh` or dynamically linked binaries that need to access `/lib`, so you'd need to go deeper for practical use, e.g. `setfacl -m user:joe:0 /*; setfacl -d user:joe /bin /lib`).

Read permission on a directory gives the right to enumerate the entries. Giving execute permission without giving read permission is occasionally useful: the names of entries serve as passwords to access them. I can't think of any use in giving read or write permission to a directory without execute permission.

Answer (score 45):

No. Root folder permission limits child files permission. You can try it.

```
$ mkdir rootdir
$ touch ./rootdir/childfile
$ chmod 777 ./rootdir/childfile
$ chmod 600 rootdir
$ cat ./rootdir/childfile
```

I get this:

```
$ cat: ./rootfolder/childfile: permission denied
```

Answer (score 7):

You can make the child directory writable even the parent directory is not.  I do this for groups.

For example: parent directory is owned by group coder

```
drwxr-sr-x
```

child directory

```
drwxrwsr-x
```

You (any member of the coder group) can still write to the child directory but not to the parent directory.

Comment: Is `setuid` necessary in this example?

Comment: Have not experimented with that.  Did not do anything else.

Comment: I've checked. `setuid` is not needed. So you can swap `s` with `x` in your example.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the hard link to access the file even if you don't have an execute privilege on the parent directory. But the catch here is you have to create the hard linking before you lose your execute privilege on the parent directory

```
$ ln foo/bar/test_privs privs_test_checking
```