# Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

In my CMS, I noticed that directories need the executable bit (`+x`) set for the user to open them. Why is the execute permission required to read a directory, and how do directory permissions in Linux work?

Comment: See also [In Linux, "Write" Permission Is Equivalent To "Execute" For Directories?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18095) and [Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858)

Comment: Think like this: the directory entry contains file *names*, so "reading" a directory is listing the files, "using" the directory is accessing the files.

Comment: With directory __execute bit set__, you are allowed to __traverse its  hierachy__. Given you belong to "other" people and only have execute bit set (`chmod 771 dirOne`) you cannot list dirOne content. BUT if it contains a sub directory "dirTwo" with rights set like (`chmod 774 dirTwo`) you can actually list its content !

Comment: Future visitors should also see related question on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/q/1106822/295286

Answer (score 497, accepted):

When applying permissions to directories on Linux, the permission bits have different meanings than on regular files.

- The **read bit** (`r`) allows the affected user to list the files within the directory
- The **write bit** (`w`) allows the affected user to create, rename, or delete files within the directory, and modify the directory's attributes
- The **execute bit** (`x`) allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside
- The **sticky bit** (`T`, or `t` if the execute bit is set for others) states that files and directories within that directory may only be deleted or renamed by their owner (or root)

Comment: Great answer, but I think the last sentence is misleading. None of these permissions can be overridden per-file actually. Here “access” is a bit ambiguous: `+x` on the directory grants access to files inodes through this *specific* directory (nothing less, nothing more, well… maybe `chdir` needs `+x` too). To read or write the contents of one file, the user also needs `+r`/`+w` on this file, but those are distinct permissions (they do not override anything).

Comment: The immutable flag is filesystem specific and it won't precisely override those permissions, that's why I think the last sentence is misleading :-)

Comment: I think it might be useful to mention ACL in this and other answers, cause their application for some directories can be misleading if one will consider only information provided by Chris Down

Comment: Seems that this answer doesn't mention the combined effect of write bit and execute bit, as Baldrick's answer mentions below? i.e. if you only have write permission but not execution permission, then it's quite useless.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez "`+x` on the directory grants access to files inodes" -- This seems like a good nemonic, but perhaps doesn't tell the whole story? Without the execute bit set on a directory, you can't change the filename of a file in that directory. I'm wondering why this is, because the filename is stored in a directory entry, not an inode.

Comment: @Chris, With only write permission but not execute, can I know the inodes of stuff in the directory?

Comment: @Chris: What “directory attributes” can you modify if you have write permission, but aren’t the owner?

Comment: Had a directory I couldn't write to, adding execute flag fixed it.  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Last point: For a directory with sticky bit, the required role for renaming/deleting a file inside is "file owner or someone with `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE`", am I right?

Comment: A good explanation on why `x` is needed in addition to `w`: https://askubuntu.com/a/1244013/41885

Answer (score 353):

First, think: What is a directory? It's just a list of items (files and other directories) that live within. So: directory = list of names.

**Read bit** = If set, you can read this list. So, for example, if you have a directory named `poems`:

- You can `ls poems` and you'll get a list of items living within (`-l` won't reveal any details!).
- You can use command-line completion i.e. `touch poems/so <TAB> poems/somefile`.
- You cannot make `poems` your working directory (i.e. `cd` into it).

**Write bit** = If set, you can modify this list i.e. you can {add,rename,delete} names on it. But! You can actually do it only if the execute bit is set too.

**Execute bit** = Make this directory your working directory i.e. `cd` into it. You need this permission if you want to:

- access (read, write, execute) items living within.
- modify the list itself i.e. add, rename, delete names on it (of course the write bit must be set on the directory).

**Interesting case 1**: If you have write + execute permissions on a directory, you can {delete,rename} items living within even if you don't have write perimission on those items. (use sticky bit to prevent this)

**Interesting case 2**: If you have execute (but not write) permission on a directory AND you have write permission on a file living within, you cannot delete the file (because it involves removing it from the list). However, you can erase its contents e.g. if it's a text file you can use vi to open it and delete everything. The file will still be there, but it will be empty.

Summary:

**Read bit** = You can read the names on the list.
**Write bit** = You can {add,rename,delete} names on the list IF the execute bit is set too.
**Execute bit** = You can make this directory your working directory.

PS: The article mentioned by Kusalananda is a good read.

Comment: Thinking about directory as a list makes things more clear and logical.

Comment: Great answer, but too focused on the term "working directory". I need the `x` bit for *any* access to this file: for `cat a/b/c/d`, I need the `x` bit on all `a`, `b` and `c`, even if I don't use them as cwd.

Comment: This is where I found out you can't write unless it's executable too! Case 2 is also interesting, great answer!

Comment: Another note is that even if you have `x` permission on the directory, if you don't have `x` permission on **the file** within, you can't really "execute" the file. You can only `cat` it for example, but you can't run the file itself.

Comment: If you want to `ls -l` work for a folder, need both `r` and `x` permission.

Comment: For case 2: I assume you are also not able to rename or add files, right?

Comment: Also, having write permission without execution is useless, right?

Comment: I would add: *program files written in scripting languages must also be set as readable to be executed*. Taken from: https://superuser.com/a/684242/636058.

Comment: I will save this answer as most clear and authoritative on the question. I only suggest to explain that to list subfolders content you need x on every and each level of the path

Comment: I wonder why we can't rename files within the directory having the `w` permission and not having the `x` one? Is it in some way related to the fact that for renaming we need access to the inode?

Answer (score 103):

I have prepared this table with all the possible permissions and their practical effects.

| dir permissions | Octal | del rename create files | dir list | read file contents | write file contents | cd dir | cd subdir | subdir list | access subdir files |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **---** | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **-W-** | 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **R--** | 4 |  | only file names (*) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **RW-** | 6 |  | only file names (*) |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **--X** | 1 |  |  | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
| **-WX** | 3 | ✔ |  | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
| **R-X** | 5 |  | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
| **RWX** | 7 | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |

(*) *Only file names*: other attributes such as size or date are not accesible. E.g. you can use tab key to autocomplete but not ls command.

**Some thoughts**:

- With **X unset**, R and W are mostly useless.
- **X** alone **disabling RW** gives you a false sense of security since you could blindly read and write file contents and access subdirectories. You should be sure that every direct children of the directory have explicit permissions.
- Rarely you will use other values than:

  - **0**: No access.
  - **1**: Minimum access allowing traversing.
  - **5**: Allow reading / writing, but not altering the structure of the directory tree itself.
  - **7**: Full access.

Comment: Great summary chart. Makes me wonder what someone was thinking to have `-W-` be functionally equivalent to `---` for directories. Not very intuitive. Of course these types of low-level bits often aren't.

Comment: And similarly, have `R--` be functionally equivalent to `RW-`.

Comment: Another typical use case is the ability to change permissions on the directory itself. How is that affected by the different combos?

Comment: I tested this on my mac, but with `-W-`, I could rename the directory (in a directory with a sticky bit) but not with `---`. That seems to be a difference

Comment: @David, You are missing the sticky bit.

Comment: @David What does the last column (**access subdir files**) mean?

Comment: @user7681202, Del, rename, create, read, write... as long as the subdir permissions are RWX.

Comment: "_Only file names: other attributes such as size or date are not accesible._" This is not completely true. Yes, you do not have access to the respective target files inodes, which store all the attributes. But some file systems cache part of that in the directory entries: Basically, you have access to everything that is returned in the `dirent` by `readdir(3)`. In POSIX this includes (besides the name) at least the inode number; on Linux furthermore the file type.

Comment: Dang, the notation was confusing. In countries like Japan or Korea, `X` means "doesn't work, false, wrong" etc, and `O` means "correct, functioning, true", etc. So, when interpreted that the "X" marks mean "doesn't work with that permission".

Comment: Best answer for me; actual operations (not just generalities like "access"), minimal text/digestible ref fmt.

Comment: @DamnVegetables I have edited the table replacing X by ✔.

Answer (score 48):

[Here is a good article on this.](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030424.html)

Summary:

A directory with its `x` bit set allows the user to `cd` (change directory)
into this directory, and access the files in it.

Details:

- Read (`r`)

  > The ability to read the names of files stored in this directory.
- Write (`w`)

  > The ability to rename files in the directory, create new files, or delete existing files, if you also have Execute permissions. If you don't have execute perms, then write perms are meaningless.
- Execute (`x`)

  > The ability to `cd` into this directory, and access the files in this directory.

Here are a few examples that should make it easier to understand:

```
# "Full Access".  Reegen can list, create, delete, rename, delete,
# and stat any files in dir.
# Access to file contents is subject to the permissions
# of the file itself.
# New files can be created, any file can be deleted, regardless of
# file permissions.
drwx------  1 reegen    reegen          4096 Jan 01 2003  dir

# Reegen can do everything in the "Full Access" list except create,
# delete, or rename files in this directory.
dr-x------  1 reegen    reegen          4096 Jan 01 2003  dir

# Reegen can do everything in the "Full Access" list except list the
# filenames in this directory.  If she suspects there is a file
# named "program" she can list it, but cannot do an 'ls'
# of the directory itself.  She can access any file (file
# permissions permitting) if she knows its name.  She can
# create new files, or rename/delete existing ones.
d-wx------  1 reegen    reegen          4096 Jan 01 2003  dir

# Reegen cannot create or delete any files in this directory.
# She can access any file (permissions permitting) if she
# knows its name already.
d--x------  1 reegen    reegen          4096 Jan 01 2003  dir
```

There is even more information in the [Hacking Linux Exposed article](http://www.hackinglinuxexposed.com/articles/20030424.html).

Answer (score 12):

From [Robert Love](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Love)'s book "LINUX System Programming" chapter 1 section permission-

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For any operation accessing a file or directory, it must first resolve the path to the file or directory. The resolution requires the user has execute permission on all directories along the path, except the final path component. So for directories, you can think of the execute bit means "resolvable".

Take path `/a/b/c.txt` as an example, say the user has 1) execute permission on `/` and `/a`; 2) has read permission on `/a/b`; 3) read and write permission on `/a/b/c.txt`.

- The user will fail to read (list) `/a`, because it has no read permission. But the path resolution doesn't fail.
- The user will be able to read (list) `/a/b`, because the user has execute permission on `/`, `/a` and read permission on `/a/b`. Note that, when reading `/a/b`, the filename `c.txt` is visible, but the metadata (e.g. filesize) and the content is not, because the filename is stored with the directory, not with the file, but the metadata is stored in the inode of the file.
- The user will fail to read `/a/b/c.txt`, because when resolving the path from `/` to `/a` to `/a/b`, it fails at `/a/b` since the user doesn't have execute permission.

See also [how a pathname is resolved to a file](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/path_resolution.7).

Comment: So you need 'x' on a folder to read the content of a file directly inside the folder itself? Why?

Answer (score 3):

An useful analogy is to think of each file as a book, and each directory as a room where the books are kept.

There are rules to be able to list all the names in a room: the read bit for directories. Rules to remove a book from the room: the write bit for directories. And rules to enter a room and explore: the resulting directory execute bit.

Those rules are separate and different than the rules for each book. There are rules to allow someone to open a book and read its contents: the read bit(s) for each file. There are rules to modify the contents of a book: the write bit(s) for each file. And to execute a file: the execute bit(s) for each file.

I write bit(s) because there are three bits for each action. There is one read bit for the owner, one read bit for the group(s) and a read bit for everyone else (others). If any of those three bits is set for an specific user, that user has the read bit active. It doesn't matter how that bit was found to be active either by **u**ser or **g**roup or **o**ther, it has the same effective results.

Thus, an user could be allowed to enter a room and remove books from the library but not allowed to read the contents of same book.

That is why a **read** bit for directories is required: to control who is allowed to list the room contents (book titles).

And the **execute** bit is used to control who can enter the room of books.

Comment: I like your example. The rooms with books is better than simply lists of books.  In your examples the 'r' allow reading the index of books but to cat a file you must also 'x' to effectively enter on it and use the list itself to locate a book. But question: what happen if you have only x and not r on a folder. You can enter, but not la and not autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

[access(2) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html)

> A file is accessible only if the permissions on each of the
> directories in the path prefix of pathname grant search (i.e.,
> execute) access.  If any directory is inaccessible, then the access()
> call fails, regardless of the permissions on the file itself.

[path_resolution(7) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)

This man page explains how a pathname is resolved in relation to permissions

> Step 2: walk along the path
>
> If the process does not have search permission on the current lookup
> directory, an EACCES error is returned ("Permission denied").

"seach permission" means execute permission of directories.

Comment: Does this add anything that isn't already in the earlier 8 answers?

Answer (score -2):

The meaning of Execute for directories is quite clear. Since there is no Traverse permission, unlike Windows, you must overload something. The designers picked Execute, That causes endless confusion. As a computer security guy assigning Execute rights to something you don't intend to actually Execute looks dodgy.

Comment: The invention of the execute permission bit pre-dates the invention of the concept of a distinct traverse permission by about two decades.  This answer's logic depends from a historic timeline that is nothing like that of the real world, and also fails to notice the existence of `GENERIC_EXECUTE` and what it is.