# Permissions for making some some (but not all) files visible directly under a directory

Tags: permissions, files

On wikipedia I [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions) the following:

> The read permission, which grants the ability to read a file. When set
>   for a directory, this permission grants the ability to read the names
>   of files in the directory (but not to find out any further information
>   about them such as contents, file type, size, ownership, permissions,
>   etc.)

With this, is there any way to only let people in my group see (read) **the names** of a subset of the files/directories I have in a directory?

E.g. if I have

```
A ---- B
  |
  |----C
  |
  |----D
```

can I modify permissions so that members of my groups can only see (read) **the names** `C` and `D` but not `B`? (if they `ls A` for example).

If this is not possible, what is the **rationale behind it**? What if I want to completely hide some files I have in  my folders? What would the "UNIX way" of dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No.** You cannot make only some files in a directory "invisible" to those that do not belong to certain group.

Have a look at the question [Why do directories need the executable (X) permission to be opened?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened) - the subject is nicely covered there, so I won't just replicate it here. The important thing to understand is that a directory is a separate entity - just as a file - so any permissions can only affect it as a whole.