# How to search folder with only x set (execution) permission

Tags: permissions, directory, executable, search

I have read that if folder has only x set permission to execute it actually means that you are permitted to search this directory. So how to search it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand. “Search” permission is a bit of a misnomer; if you have execution permission but not read permission on a directory, you can access a file in this directory only if you know its name. That is, given a name, you can search the file with this name (and, more importantly, you can access the file that you find). You do that in the usual way, by accessing the file `directoryname/filename`. You can't browse the list of entries in the directory, so you can't make more advanced searches such as pattern matching. That would require the read permission; the read permission is precisely what lets you browse the list of entries in the directory.

See also [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened)