# chmod -R 644 ~/Documents

Tags: chmod

I recently noticed that all of the files in my `~/Documents` were somehow incorrectly given executable status. This proved annoying as trying to opening any file gave me a message box saying it was executable. I tried doing a recursive `chmod` like:

```
chmod -R 644 ~/Documents
```

Unfortunately, this made the whole Documents folder inaccessible. What went wrong?

Comment: You can't enter into folders that you don't have execute permissions to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to have the execute bit set on a directory to allow the affected user to enter it and access files and directories inside, and you've removed it (your command removes the execute bit from both the files and the folders). There is information about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/10762). The following command should fix it:

```
find ~/Documents -type d -exec chmod a+x {} +
```

Comment: Yeah. I get it now. Directories always need executable bit set. Thanks.

Comment: @BernhardHeijstek: Almost.  It *can* make sense for a directory not to have execute (actually) search permission.  If a directory has 644 permission, for example, you can refer to files under that directory only if you already know their names.  But I've hardly ever used that feature myself.

Comment: Isn't that read, not execute, that prevents "searching"?

Comment: @janmoesen That would depend on what your definition of "searching" is.

Comment: @Chris thanks for sharing this info. i believe i removed the executable bit on my home folder a long time ago, couldn't figure out what went wrong. only now i'm realizing what i did...

Comment: @BernhardHeijstek: Hmm, experiment shows that I might have gotten that wrong -- or maybe my system is behaving strangely.

Comment: @ChrisDown: I was referring to Keith's suggestion to use 644 and his choice of "search". What I meant, was: you should set `-r` to prevent people from reading the contents of the directory, rather than `-x`. If you set `-x`, access is not possible at all.