# Why is bash giving me (apparently) conflicting information about a file?

Tags: permissions, directory, ls, symlink

#### Background

I am working on a RHEL 5 cluster. I want my Fortran program to read the file `/home/bob/inputs/input_1`

1. I asked Bob to give me permission to read all contents of `inputs`:

   ```
   [bob@server]$ chmod -R a+r /home/bob/inputs/*
   ```
2. I linked these to a shared directory:

   ```
   [david@server]$ ln -s /home/bob/inputs/ /home/share/inputs/
   ```
3. My (Fortran) program tried to read `/home/share/inputs/input_1` and said:

   ```
   File /home/share/inputs/input_1 not found!
   ```
4. I tried to locate the file myself (in the process, bob gave `a+rwx` permissions):

   ```
   [david@server]$ls -ltrh /home/share/inputs/input_1
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob 33 Oct 25 15:42 /home/share/inputs/input_1 -> /home/bob/inputs/input_1
   ```

   From this, I concluded that a) `inputs_1` exists and b) all users have `rwx` permission.
5. I tried to read it:

   ```
   [david@server]$ more /home/share/inputs/input_1 
   /home/share/inputs/input_1: No such file or directory
   ```

   And am told that it does not exist.
6. I look for the target file `/home/bob/inputs/input_1` but am denied permission.

   ```
   [david@server]$ls -ltrh /home/bob/inputs/input_1
   ls: /home/bob/inputs/input_1 Permission denied
   ```
7. Something bizzare happens if I `ls` the directory contents:

   ```
   [david@server]$ls -ltrh /home/bob/inputs/
   ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? input_1
   ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? input_2
   ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? input_3
   ... (n-4 lines omitted) 
   ?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? input_n
   ```

   although if bob does this, he gets:

   ```
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob  269 May 24  input_1
   ... (n-2 lines omitted) 
   -rwxrwxrwx 1 bob bob 2.0K Jan 19  input_n
   ```

#### Questions:

- Is there a simple explanation for this apparently (to me) inconsistent behavior?
- Where do I go from here?

Comment: Maybe a time for a refreshing reboot / fsck?

Comment: Do you have permission to /home/share/inputs? Meaning, can you cd there?

Comment: @HaiVu no. I thought `chmod a+r *` would be sufficient.

Comment: Go with Chris Card's solution: you need access to /home/bob/inputs (i.e. must be able to cd into it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need execute permissions on `/home/bob/inputs`. You can set it with:

```
chmod a+x /home/bob/inputs
```

Comment: Getting bob to `chmod a+rwx /home/bob/inputs` was the solution.

Comment: You don't need `w`.

Comment: You don't need `r` either.

Comment: You will need `r` permission if you want to access files in this directory, or sub directories below it.

Comment: @HaiVu On the contrary - you need **`x`** (execute) permission to be able to access **files** in that directory - the **`r`** permission is needed to able to list the contents of the directory itself (just the file names). To see the permissions of each of the files, you need `x` on the directory - that is why there are question marks in OP's `ls` output.

Answer (score 3):

Run `ls -ld /home/bob/inputs/`. I think you'll find that bob gave you read permission on the directory, but not execute permission, i.e. something like `drwxr--r--`. On a directory, read permission lets you see the list of files while execute permission lets you access files in the directory. There are rare circumstances where it's useful to make a directory executable and not readable; the contrary is pretty useless. Almost all the time, a directory should either be accessible (readable and executable) or not accessible (neither readable nor executable).

See [Why do directories need the executable (X) permission to be opened?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened) for more explanations.

Remedy: ask bob to run `chmod a+rx ~/inputs`.