# Process owned by root can't write files

Tags: permissions, directory

I'm running a program (syslog-ng) that must read and write several files in a given path. It was failing at start, claiming that it is unable to open a file in that path.

Please, assume this directory structure:

```
/var/platform/program
```

The `platform` directory has the permission set to 0655 (not execute permission to the owner user). If I change that permissions to 0755, syslog-ng works fine.

On the other hand, I have written a small program in C that try to open and write into a file in the same directory, and it works without problem when running as root, but syslog-ng is failing...

What can be the problem in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

syslog wants probably to `chdir` to the directory and needs therefore the execute bit set on the directory.

See [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, if it only wants to read/write from inside `/var/platform/program/something_more`? It was failing when try to read the configuration file, that is stored on that way

Comment: You need  the x bit as well to write files in the directory if you're not root. `root` can do anything in any directory regardless of the permissions. Most probably syslog-ng is not running as root or has dropped some priviledges.

Comment: Theoretically it's running as root, as it's shown by `ps ufax`

Comment: This answer put my in the right direction: I saw that syslog-ng is dropping some root privileges and that there is an option (not documented in the help output) to avoid this privileges dropping. Now, it's working like a charm. Thank you!