# What is the difference between 'ls' and 'ls -l' when I don't have execute permission on that directory?

Tags: permissions, directory

I created a directory called `folder` and took away execute permission.

```
$ mkdir folder
$ touch folder/innerFile
$ mkdir folder/innerFolder
$ chmod -x folder
```

Now if I do

```
$ ls folder
```

it outputs a list of files, but when I do

```
$ ls -l folder
```

I get

```
ls: innerFile: Permission denied
ls: innerFolder: Permission denied
```

Why is that?

Comment: Check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21263/47538) answer. It has answers to your question.

Comment: "What is the difference between 'ls' and 'ls -l' when I don't have execute permission on that directory?" Basically, it's the same as the difference between 'ls' and 'ls -l' when you ***do*** have execute permission on the directory.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ls -l` on a folder tries to [`stat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/stat.3posix.html) its contents, whereas `ls` doesn't:

```
$ strace ls folder -l
...
lstat("folder/innerFolder", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
getxattr("folder/innerFolder", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
getxattr("folder/innerFolder", "system.posix_acl_default", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
lstat("folder/innerFile", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=40, ...}) = 0
getxattr("folder/innerFile", "system.posix_acl_access", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
getxattr("folder/innerFile", "system.posix_acl_default", 0x0, 0) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
...
```

That's why you get a "permission denied" with `ls -l` and not with `ls`.