# Group member cannot list files in directory made by group

Tags: filesystems, group, access-control

I am using Centos 6.6.

I made a group with the following call

```
 sudo groupadd www-OtagoHarbour
 sudo usermod -G www-OtagoHarbour apache
 sudo usermod -G www-OtagoHarbour OtagoHarbour
```

When I enter

```
more /etc/group
```

I see

```
www-OtagoHarbour:x:501:apache,OtagoHarbour
```

I enter

```
sudo chown apache /var/www/dropbox
```

then

```
 sudo chgrp -R www-OtagoHarbour /var/www/dropbox
 sudo chgrp -R www-OtagoHarbour /var/www
 sudo chmod -R g+r /var/www/dropbox
 sudo chmod -R g+r /var/www
```

However, when I log is as OtagoHarbour and enter

```
 ls /var/www/dropbox
```

I get

```
 ls: cannot open directory /var/www/dropbox: Permission denied/var/www/dropbox
```

EDIT:

```
$ ls -ld /var/www/dropbox /var/www /var
drwxr-xr-x. 22 root   root            4096 Mar 25  2014 /var
drwxr-xr-x. 17 root   www-OtagoHarbour 4096 Jan  9 22:29 /var/www
drwxrwx--x.  2 apache www-OtagoHarbour 4096 Jan 10 11:30 /var/www/dropbox
```

Comment: Please post output of `ls -ld /var/www/dropbox /var/www /var`.

Comment: See [Why do directories need the executable (X) permission to be opened?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/65304)

Comment: Sepahrad.  I edited my question to post that output.  Thanks,

Comment: Steeldriver.  I tried "sudo chmod g+x /var/www/dropbox"  but still have the permission error.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal file permissions are OK. But the trailing dot in the permission field

```
drwxrwx--x.  [...] /var/www/dropbox
```

shows that there is a SELinux security context for this directory. If SELinux is active (which can be checked by the command `sestatus`) then this may prevent the access.

I am not familiar with SELinux, though. Thus I cannot tell you how to change those settings. If that is the reason then you should ask a new question specificly  about the necessary SELinux settings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry about my own tardiness in replying.  I was getting familiar with SELinux.  I put SELinux into permissive mode but, unfortunately, that did not resolve the problem.  "ls /var/www/dropbox"  still results in "ls: cannot open directory /var/www/dropbox: Permission denied".  Thanks,

Comment: I restarted the computer and that fixed the problem.  Thanks,

Comment: @OtagoHarbour You mean the reboot was necessary to disable SELinux, or didn't the problem have anything to do with SELinux?

Comment: I suspect the latter.  I switched SELinux to permissive mode using "echo 0 >/selinux/enforce" as root and sestatus returned "current mode: permissive" but my problem persisted.  I logged out and logged back in again after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309820/permission-denied-writing-in-directories-with-gw-mode-on-ubuntu).  It would appear that logging out and logging back in again is necessary for usermod to take effect.  Thanks,