# Why do I get permission denied when using mv although directory rights are correct?

Tags: files, permissions, osx, directory, mv

I get permission denied when trying to move folder `Music` via `mv` although directory owner is set to my user and user permissions are set to 7. What's going on?

(I know that I could use sudo but I want to find out what's wrong. Something smells fishy here). Ps: I am on Mac OS X El Capitan.

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Comment: Anyone stumbling upon the same error, it might be because you're trying to mv a file which is open. Not the OP case though, just saying so it might help.

Answer (score 72):

I was using Windows Subsystem for Linux. I had the directory open in a different bash instance. Closing it let me move the directory.

Comment: In VS Code with remote on WSL I had to close editor and open up a terminal to WSL outside of that VS Code project.

Comment: this stems from the NTFS limitation that prevents renaming directories which have a handle open to anything below

Comment: For me it was a file explorer with the tree view (on the left) still open on the directory.

Answer (score 28):

Do note that, when in folder `a`, moving `b` to `c`, the folder permissions of `a` determine what you can do.

In this case, the permissions on `.` will be most important.

Observe that the permissions are more complex than simply `rwx`.  Your `music` folder has an `@` at the end, the `.` folder has a `+` at the end.

- Use `xattr -h` to determine the complex permissions for the @ symbol.
- Use `getfacl` to determine the ACL for the + symbol.

Comment: Do you have a resource that covers "complex permissions", as you call them?

Comment: [`man xattr`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) might be a good starting point.

Comment: nope, no manual entry.  I was able to Google around to find another name for it: [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#Linux), if anyone else wants to learn more.

Comment: Or use `ls -la@e`. Most likely here, there was a `deny delete` ACLs that also prevents renaming.

Comment: @user1717828, check [the `chmod` man page on OS/X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Using `ls -la@e` I found this: Could this be it? `0: group:everyone deny delete`. If yes, how can I fix this? It seems default setting for standard folders on Mac OS like `Documents`, `Dropbox` or `Desktop`. Should I even mess with these attributes?

Comment: @Timo, those ACLs do prevent deleting or renaming those directories. Presumably, they were put there for a reason, like some applications rely on them being there and would fail otherwise.

Comment: This was it! I had a terminal open to the machine over SSH too, but that wasn't the problem. Folder 'a' was under root ownership.

Answer (score 13):

Seems like as if there was at least 1 file somewhere deep in that directory that didn't have right permissions.

So, what I did was:

```
sudo chown -R valmar ./Music
sudo chmod -R 755 ./Music
```

Now it works.

Comment: Whatever the problem was, giving execute permissions to music files should not be the solution.

Comment: And it seems unlikely that an object *in* a directory could interfere with your ability to rename that directory.

Comment: I know it's weird but that did the trick. Using chmod and chown on the directory itself had no effect.

Comment: is it possible that `chmod 755` removed the special '@' permissions on the Music folder?

Comment: @HorusKol, or the chown. The OP's symptoms would match the directories having a _deny delete_ ACLs, but at least on Yosemite, doing a chown or chmod 755 does not delete that ACL. You'd need `chmod -a 'everyone deny delete' Music` for that. It could be different in El Capitan.

Comment: @HorusKol Nope, permissions look like this now: `drwxr-xr-x@  12 valmar  staff    408  6 Okt 15:32 Music`

Comment: Must be the additional x bits for group, etc...http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work

Answer (score 8):

The problem here likely has to do with the Access Control List (ACL) of the Music folder. The ACL is a separate permission system to the regular POSIX ones that are normally listed by `ls -l`. Some other directories in the Home folder and elsewhere also have ACLs.

To see the ACLs within the home directory, use:

```
/bin/ls -le ~
```

You will likely see a rule like `0: group:everyone deny delete` for the Music directory. As you noted you could override the problem with `sudo`. If you don't want to do that (or can't), you have other options, given that you're the owner of the file. You can strip off the offending entry from the Music directory's ACL, based on its index (0 in the example I gave above):

```
/bin/chmod -a# 0 Music
```

Or you can strip off all entries in the ACL:

```
/bin/chmod -N Music
```

Now you can move the directory around (subject to the regular POSIX permissions). If you want to put the ACL back after the move, you could use:

```
/bin/chmod +a "group:everyone deny delete" Music_tmp
```

And use `/bin/ls -le` again to confirm the ACL is as you want it. Check out the ACL examples in `man chmod` for more info. In particular, this intro is helpful:

> Each file has one ACL, containing an ordered list of entries.  Each entry refers to a user or group, and grants or denies a set of permissions.  In cases where a user and a group exist with the same name, the user/group name can be prefixed with "user:" or "group:" in order to specify the type of name.

#### ACL Order

I don't think that man page explains the rules around ordering, but [this page](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-acl-use.htm) explains the order rules for ACLs clearly. In particular, an explicit `deny` rule will be applied before an explicit `allow` rule. So, as long as the `group:everyone deny delete` entry is in place, it's not possible to give your user permission to delete with an `allow` rule. This is because permission is denied to the `everyone` group, which includes you, and that rule will be applied first.

Comment: I don’t know why this was downvoted. The `everyone deny delete` ACL entry on macOS’ default home directories is the _actual_ reason the directories can neither be moved nor deleted. (Also, do note the OS might re-create them anytime.)

Comment: this answer ROCKED!!!  holy crap, these new ACL's are a HUGE PITA.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when a set of programs was running in a directory I was trying to remove. In order to move the directory, I had to first kill all running programs from that directory.

In the following commands, be **very careful** about how you select the name of your program. I used the following commands, for reference:

```
ps aux | grep -i [NAME_OF_ANNOYING_PROGRAM] | grep -v grep
# make sure that you are only about to kill the programs you want to kill

ps aux | grep -i [NAME_OF_ANNOYING_PROGRAM] | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | sudo xargs kill -9
sudo mv /usr/local/[DIR_FOR_ANNOYING_PROGRAM] /usr/local/[DIR_FOR_ANNOYING_PROGRAM]2
```

The general procedure is:

1. kill all programs running from the directory in question
2. attempt to rename directory
3. if that fails, force kill (`kill -9` with a lot of *caution*) all programs from the directory
4. attempt to rename directory
5. if that fails, see if the program is running again, I.e. that it has been restarted by some daemon program running from a different directory
6. force kill the daemon program that restarts the annoying program
7. force kill the annoying program
8. rename directory
9. profit

Comment: I don't think the OP likely has any programs running from the ~/Music directory. Anyway he said he doesn't want to use sudo, which this answer does.

Comment: All I'm saying is I had that situation. Might be helpful to someone even though it wasn't helpful to the OP.

Comment: It's possibly helpful for someone, certainly -- that's why I didn't downvote. But I think the intention of StackExchange is that the posted answers actually answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Another potential issue, if you're meaning for this answer to be of general use to a novice: you don't provide any warnings about choosing your search terms very carefully in the first `grep` and checking it. Whatever you're putting in to that first `grep` will choose from the pool of all running programs and `kill` it with root privileges...

Comment: @spinup truth be told I didn't see that he didn't want to use sudo so I thought I was answering the question asked. I can move to a new question if you think that's best.

Comment: @spinup also I edited my answer to add caution

Comment: Nice, @Watts, I think that's a big improvement

Answer (score 0):

That also can happen when one of the files inside is write-protected. I had the edge case today when `access.log` was write-protected to Apache, which was already stopped. I just removed this file, so further I was able to move parent directory.

Answer (score -2):

I had same Issue. What helped was the Almighty **sudo** command. prepend that to your
mv command and try again. That should work

```
sudo mv <old_name> <new_path>
```

Hope it works

Comment: sure, sudo does the trick. assuming you are on your own mashine. in web developement, access rights aren't as easy, especially if you work as for external companies and only have access to the deployment pipeline