# permission denied on ~/.ssh for the owner of it!

Tags: linux, permissions

I have set the owner of /home/jack/.ssh to the jack and also give it the permissions as follows:

```
-rw-------  1 jack jack 1679 Oct 10 01:41 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 jack jack  396 Oct 10 01:41 id_rsa.pub
-rwxrwx---+ 1 jack jack  884 Oct 10 01:48 known_hosts 
and 
drw------- 2 jack jack 4096 Oct 13 18:00 .ssh
```

but jack can not open /home/jack/known_hosts file. What is wrong with that?

Comment: See [How do directory permissions in Linux work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work) - in particular, the significance of the *execute bit*

Comment: Post the output of `ls -ld /home/jack /home/jack/.ssh` and `getfacl  /home/jack/.ssh/known_hosts`. Can jack read other files in the same directory? Also copy-paste the exact command and the error message when you try to read the file.

Answer (score 6):

In short, as user jack run `chmod u+x ~/.ssh`. This will allow programs jack runs to be able to read files under the directory `~.ssh`.

In an `ls` listing of a file, the `x` means you can *execute* or run the file, but for directories it means you can *search* the contents underneath.