# NixOS: How do I change my group and clean up the bad configurations?

Tags: nixos

This is my current users expression

```
   users.users = {
     john = {
       name = "john";
       group = "users";
       extraGroups = [
         "wheel" "disk" "audio" "video" "networkmanager" "systemd-journal"
       ];
       isNormalUser = true;
       uid = 1000;
       home = "/home/john";
       createHome = true;
     };
   };
```

My problem is that `group = "users";` allows all users to see my files. How can I make the `group = "john";` and clean up permissions on all of my files in the home directory? Is it possible to do this in my configuration.nix file? Also would restarting in one of these bad configurations mess up permissions again? How do I remove these old configurations so they cannot be accessed?

Answer (score 1):

To have own group, add `users.groups.johns = { name = "John's"; members = ["john"]; gid = 1666 };`.
See also `man configuration.nix` for all the options.

Comment: Ok but how do I fix my current home directory? The group is users on all of the folders and that could be a security problem.

Comment: @JohnMercier `chgrp --recursive johns /home/john/`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change group to accomplish what you want.

```
[danbst@station:~]$ ls -l /home
total 12
drwx------ 47 danbst users 12288 Jan 31 13:43 danbst
```

I am in `users` group, but my `/home/danbst` is accessible only by me.
See more about executuable bit on directories in [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)