# touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied

Tags: files, permissions, touch

I am trying to create a file in a directory but I am getting:

```
`touch`: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Here are my commands:

```bsh
[user@xxx api]$ ls -l
total 184
...
drwxrwxr-x  2 root root   4096 2016-04-12 14:38 public 
..
[user@xxx api]$ cd ./public
[user@xxx public]$ touch test
touch: cannot touch ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't edit the contents of the **public** directory if you don't have **write** and **execute** access.

- You indicate you are attempting to create a new file. If the `test` file doesn't already exist in `public`, `touch` will attempt to create a new file. It cannot do this without the *write* and *execute* permissions over the parent directory. Execute is required to traverse the directory; write is required to add the inode entry for the new file. Apparently, you don't have one or both of these permissions.
- If the `test` file does already exist in `public`, `touch` will, by default, update the modification time of the file. Only **write** access to the *file* is required for this, as the modification date/time is stored in the file's inode. If the file already exists, you will need to inspect the file's permissions using a command like `ls -l public/test` to determine if you have write access.

---

The permissions bitmask on the directory, `rwxrwxr-x`, means:

- the `root` user, i.e. the owner of the directory, has write privileges to the *directory* as indicated by the first `rwx` block. This user can also read the directory (the `r` bit) and traverse it to access its contents (the `x` bit).
- members of the `root` group, i.e. the group on the directory, who are not themselves the `root` user, also have similar privileges to read, write and traverse the *directory* as indicated by the second `rwx` block

All other users only have read and execute rights, as indicated by the last `r-x` block. As noted, for directories, execute permissions allow you to traverse that directory and access its contents. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/36355) for more clarity on this.

## How do I get permissions?

You will need to talk to your system administrator (which might be you!) to do one of the following:

- Make you the **owner of the `public/` directory** using a command like `chown user public/`. This will be suitable if you are the only user who will need to have edit rights.
- Create a **new group with a suitable name**, perhaps `publiceditors`, and set this as the group on the `public/` directory using a command like `chgrp publiceditors public/`. Ensure you and any other users who require the ability to modify the directory are listed as members of the group. This approach works where multiple users need edit capability.
- Make your user account a **member of the `root` group** (not something I would recommend).
- Provide you with access to **log in or masquerade as `root`**, such as with `sudo` or `su` with the `root` password
- Change the **rights on the directory** to **grant all users write permissions**, using a command like `chmod o+w public`. Be aware that this gives *everyone* on the box the ability to edit and delete files in the public directory.* You may not want this!

*<sub>In the absence of other access control enforcement, such as mandatory access control in the kernel.</sub>

## What do *read*, *write* and *execute* permissions mean in the context of a directory?

Assuming you're on a Linux box, on a directory, a read permission bit allows you to read the directory listing. The write permission bit allows you to update the directory listed, which is required for **creating** a file*, **editing the name** of a file, **unlinking** (deleting) a file. The execute bit allows you to traverse the directory, access its files etc. More information on [Linux directory permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work).

<sub>* Actually, you're linking a file into the directory. Most times you will do this at the point of file creation, but there are more complex examples. For example, making a hard link to a file which originally existed elsewhere in the file system will require write access to the target directory of the link, despite the fact you're not creating a new file.</sub>

---

## Why **write** access to the *directory*?

You need to be able to write to the directory to add a reference to the relevant inode for the file you are adding.

Comment: Just to be clear, you need both write and execute permissions on a directory if you want to create a new file there. While the write allows you to edit the directory listing, you still need the execute bit to permit accessing said directory listing.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ6qv.png shows a nice chart for this.

Comment: @user.friendly I would have been searching for a lot longer if you hadn't mentioned that. Very helpful. (I can't make this message not sound sarcastic. It's sincere, I promise!)

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the **public** directory rights, only user root or a member of the group root can write into it .

What is configured (drwxrwxr-x) means :

- user root has read-write-exec rights
- group root has read-write-exec rights
- other has read-exec rights

Verify that your user is in the root group or give write access to "other" using the command :

```
chmod o+w public
```

Comment: I would advise against changing the permissions if not needed. So first decide if the dir `pulic` is supposed to provide write access to everyone. Better use `sudo` for once-in-a-while resp. exceptional tasks.

Comment: I agree. First analyse the permission needs before giving access.

Answer (score -2):

I have faced the similar issue, I found that I was a normal user and i don't have any permission to create files.
Hence, I have switched the user to root

```
command:
 su <root user>
```

It will ask for password enter your root password (if kali Linux password is toor)

This has solved my issue

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please add a few words of explanation how your solution is different from the `sudo` advice given in @CosmicOssifrage's answer.

Comment: Never work as root on such easy tasks.

Answer (score -3):

Your user don't have "write" permission. change permission using below command

```
chmod o+w public**
```

Otherwise you can set read-write-execute permission to all (Owner/Group/Other) using below command. (this option is not recommended, to understand thing you can follow this)

```
chmod 777 public**
```

Comment: How is this different to the [existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/276143/100397) from nex84?