# Adding a user to a group

Tags: bash

I have a user and a group called `awe` on my server.

It's home directory is `/home/awe`

I created a new user called `c37`.  I then ran the following command (as root)

`usermod -a -G awe c37`

Now when I'm logged in as `c37` and type `groups` I get:
`c37 awe`

But yet when I run the following commands as `c37`:
`cd /home/awe/
  ls -l`

`/bin/ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied`

Why is this? I thought adding a user to that group would give me permission to access everything that the user `awe` has access to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, home directories are created with permissions set only for the user, not for the group. Running the following will allow you to access that folder:

```
sudo chmod g+rX ~awe
```

The command `chmod` alters permissions on files and folders. The command above adds (`+`) read (`r`) and access directory (`X`) to anyone on the file/folder's (`~awe`) owner's main group (`g`).

Comment: can you explain what `g+rX` does? I can't find any of them in the man pages

Comment: @Chud37 added further explanation

Comment: Okay, I just ran that command and now my server is down! is there a way to undo it?

Comment: @Chud37 that command is safe and innocuous, it can't cause a system to stop functioning in any way. In any case, the way to remove the access you granted is `sudo  chmod   g=   ~awe` (note the space after =)

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to add a user to a group. The appropriate permissions should be grant for a group on files/directories.

Check permissions of the ~awe directory:

> ls -ld ~awe

most likely you would see

> drwx------. 14 awe awe 4096 May 16 15:37 /home/awe

to fix this run the following command while logged in as awe (or root):

> chmod g+rx ~awe

if you need write access as well, then use this command:

> chmod g+rwx ~awe

Please read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work) on how to interpret the access bit names