# How to delete unknown file that doesn't have proper permissions

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, corruption

My co-worker sent me a theme in a tar.gz file and I tried unzipping it using the archive manager GUI as I usually do for any kind of zipped file. However, it produced a corrupt file/directory that I can no longer delete.

Note that the working directory is in a directory I created in my home folder.

ls -l produces

```
???????????  ? ?        ?       ?            ? Alt_Elementary_Dark
```

Right click properties menu says that the permissions could not be determined, and all info is 'unknown' (like size,accessed,modified)

Type is said to be 'Binary (application/octet-stream)', though it should have been a directory.

What I've done to try and remove:

```
$ sudo rm -rfv Alt_Elementary_Dark
rm: cannot remove ‘Alt_Elementary_Dark’: Permission denied

$ sudo rmdir Alt_Elementary_Dark 
rmdir: failed to remove ‘Alt_Elementary_Dark’: Permission denied

$ sudo touch Alt_Elementary_Dark
touch: cannot touch ‘Alt_Elementary_Dark’: Permission denied

$ mv Alt_Elementary_Dark renamed_to_remove
mv: cannot stat ‘Alt_Elementary_Dark’: Permission denied

$ sudo mv Alt_Elementary_Dark renamed_to_remove
mv: failed to access ‘renamed_to_remove’: Permission denied

$ sudo ls -ld Alt_Elementary_Dark
ls: cannot access Alt_Elementary_Dark: Permission denied
```

Is there some other way I can remove this corrupt, unknown directory?

Comment: It looks like the filesystem does not have any information about the file. Try running `touch` on the file: `touch Alt_Elementary_Dark`

Comment: in order to remove a file you need write permissions on the directory, not the file itself. What are the permissions on the working directory?

Comment: @Elixiroflove touching provides the same permission denied results

Comment: @Dave this is within my own home directory, so my user account has full permissions. But it seems that when I sudo the root user can't do anything in my home directory (see different error on the sudo mv command). But I have full access in the working dir

Comment: I almost think you might want to run `fsck` on that filesyste. You also see output like above if there is filesystem corruption.

Comment: Is your home directory accessed via NFS?  And what's the output from [`lsattr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lsattr.1.html)?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes I believe it is on NFS, and lsattr just prints "Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on ..." for every file/dir

Comment: @RingOfStorms, see this:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/243999/why-do-question-mark-characters-appear-when-changing-the-permissions-of-director?lq=1  What does `ls -ld Alt_Elementary_Dark` show?

Comment: @AndrewHenle "ls -ld Alt_El..." just gives me the same permission denied error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

Answer (score 3):

First check the permissions of the directory the file's in.

The `ls -l` output where all except the file name are question marks matches a case of having `r`ead permission (= allowed to read the directory listing), but no `x` permission (= **not** allowed to access the files within the directory).

After adding the full `rwx` permissions for yourself for the directory, I think you'll find the `ls -l` listing will be normal, and then you'll also be able to delete the file normally.

Answer (score 0):

try to rename it and after that remove it.

Comment: Also gives no permission, I added those attempts above

Answer (score 0):

If it is associated with (application/octet-stream) it is probably a print file of some sort (gs, ps, or pcl). There are a lot of possibilities, but if you go to the cups interface or /etc/cups you should be able to see the print jobs. One is probably stuck and was moved there when a script when wrong.

Do you use any sort of PS to PDF type functionality? This could also push it there.

Comment: This file has persisted over restart so I don't believe it to be a stuck job of any sort. I also don't think this has to do with postscript to pdf because it should have just been a directory that got unzipped, there are no pdf's in what the directory should of contained.

Answer (score 0):

i have one of thease files  but thats by the by
not a solution but hopefully more information gaind
stat the file command
as follows
sudo stat then file  path leading to file /sometdirectory /somedirectory /somedirectory /alt_elermentry dark
in this case,

but it would be whatever file you could not read its
permissions placed at end of path

directory =folder (type exsactly what you see as path )
the forward slashes seperate the folder
exsample  /etc/ajaxterm or some directory /some file

Comment: It's unclear what you are proposing as the answer.

Answer (score -3):

Do `sudo chmod ugo+rwx -R .` (on the working directory). Also check for IO errors in dmesg.

Comment: I don't think this is the route, this is my home directory on the network so I don't want to mess with permissions (I probably can't even do this as it is managed elsewhere)

Comment: sweeping commands like this introduce more problems than they solve. And if the user is not able to delete these files or move them, what makes you think that he can change the ownership of these files ?

Comment: I am not suggesting to change his home directory permissions, he said he was in another directory beneath ~. To delete a file you need wx on its parent directory (and maybe r too).