# Why can't I list a directory with read permissions?

Tags: permissions, osx, fish

I created a directory `d` and a file `f` inside it. I then gave myself only read permissions on that directory. I understand this should mean I can list the files (e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)), but I can't.

```
will@wrmpb /p/t/permissions> ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 will  wheel  102  4 Oct 08:30 .
drwxrwxrwt  16 root  wheel  544  4 Oct 08:30 ..
dr--------   3 will  wheel  102  4 Oct 08:42 d
will@wrmpb /p/t/permissions> ls d
will@wrmpb /p/t/permissions>
```

If I change the permissions to write and execute, I can see the file.

```
will@wrmpb /p/t/permissions> chmod 500 d
will@wrmpb /p/t/permissions> ls d
f
will@wrmpb /p/t/permissions>
```

Why is this? I am using MacOS.

Edit: with reference to @ccorn's answer, it's relevant that I'm using fish and `type ls` gives the following:

```
will@wrmpb /p/t/permissions> type ls
ls is a function with definition
function ls --description 'List contents of directory'
    command ls -G $argv
end
```

Comment: The duplicate doesn't answer the question. It implies that you can do the thing that I demonstrate you can't. @ccorn's answer is perfect.

Comment: Wow, the Fish thing is a rather important piece of (initially) missing information.

Comment: Yes you're right, I should have added it, but it looks like the same thing would happen in bash if you `alias ls='ls -G'`, which I think many people do.

Comment: Does for me. Are you on MacOS? Maybe there's another question here. Edit: yep, I get different behaviour on Linux.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some preparations, just to make sure that `ls` does not try more things
than it should:

```sh
$ unalias ls 2>/dev/null
$ unset -f ls
$ unset CLICOLOR
```

Demonstration of the `r` directory permission:

```sh
$ ls -ld d
dr--------  3 ccorn  ccorn  102  4 Okt 14:35 d
$ ls d
f
$ ls -l d
ls: f: Permission denied
$ ls -F d
ls: f: Permission denied
```

In traditional Unix filesystems, a directory was simply a list of (name, inode
number) pairs. An inode number is an integer used as index into the filesystem's
inode table where the rest of the file metadata is stored.

The `r` permission on a directory allows to *list* the names in it,
but not to access the information stored in the inode table, that is,
getting file type, file length, file permissions etc, or opening the file.
For that you need the `x` permission on the directory.

This is why `ls -l`, `ls -F`, `ls` with color-coded output etc fail
without `x` permission, whereas a mere `ls` succeeds.

The `x` permission alone allows inode access, that is, given an explicit
name within that directory, `x` allows to look up its inode and access that directory entry's metadata:

```sh
$ chmod 100 d
$ ls -l d/f
-rw-r--r--  1 ccorn  ccorn  0  4 Okt 14:35 d/f
$ ls d
ls: d: Permission denied
```

Therefore, to open a file `/a/b/c/f` or list its metadata,
the directories `/`, `/a`, `/a/b`, and `/a/b/c` must be granted `x` permission.

Unsurprisingly, creating directory entries needs both `w` and `x` permissions:

```sh
$ chmod 100 d
$ touch d/g
touch: d/g: Permission denied
$ chmod 200 d
$ touch d/g
touch: d/g: Permission denied
$ chmod 300 d
$ touch d/g
$
```

Wikipedia has a brief overview in an article on [file system permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Permissions).

Comment: Amazing. `/bin/ls d` shows the contents for me. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so it was a redefinition issue (with `-G` for colorized output, which needs metadata, thus `x` perms). Therefore my preparations with `unalias ls` and `unset CLICOLOR`. I should have added `unset -f ls` to remove any such function definition as well. Edited.

Comment: More wiki ressources: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes

Answer (score 4):

To read a directory you also need to be able to traverse into it (the x bit). So, at minimum you need r-x for a directory to be able to access it in any way.

Comment: No, you don’t; `ls` should still be able to *list* the files in the directory, even if the directory isn’t executable.

Comment: You can leave the read permission off. You will then be able to access the files but not to list the directory's contents.

Comment: @Kusalananda - good point, indeed I use this from time to time.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - Maybe it SHOULD, but the implementation is that it doesn't.

Comment: @Soruk and so the question remains: why doesn’t it?

Comment: This isn't true. @ccorn's answer is correct. `/bin/ls d` will show the contents of the directory for me.

Comment: @wrgrs I’m curious about the output in your question then — does `ls d` really not output anything when you run it?

Comment: Yes. I'm using fish there, but with bash `/bin/ls -l d` will print nothing as well.

Comment: @wgrs that’s weird, it should print an error message (as shown in the accepted answer).