# Why ls without -l return 1 when permission to directory is r--

Tags: permissions, directory, ls

I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414832/why-dont-i-have-permission-to-ls-directories-i-own-and-have-r-w-permissions-for) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work), and found that my problem is different and more specific.

I understand the following points.

- +x on the directory grants access to files inodes through this specific directory
- meta information of a file, which is used by `ls -l`, is stored in its i-node, but file name does not belong to that

From the 2 points above, since `ls` without `-l` does not need to access the i-nodes of the files in the directory, it should successfully list the file names and return 0.

However, when I tried it on my machine, the file names are listed, but there were some warnings like `permission denied`, and the return code is 1.

```
b03705028@linux7 [~/test] chmod 500 permission/
b03705028@linux7 [~/test] ls --color=no permission/
f1*
b03705028@linux7 [~/test] chmod 400 permission/
b03705028@linux7 [~/test] ls --color=no permission/
ls: 無法存取 'permission/f1': 拒絕不符權限的操作
f1
b03705028@linux7 [~/test] echo $0
bash
```

The Chinese characters basically talk about `permission denied`

My unix distribution is `Linux 4.17.11-arch1`

Comment: Hi David, unfortunately I cannot reproduce your problem.  Using bash `rm -rf lala; mkdir lala; chmod 400 lala; command ls lala` is successful for me.  The `command` only makes sure that no alias of`ls` is used.  Could you please extend your question with the exact commands you type in to show the problem? (i.e., make a minimal working demonstration of what you observe)

Comment: Hi stefan, I use `echo $0` to verify that I'm using `bash` too. May I ask which Unix distribution are you using? I've updated the problem to include the commands I used.

Comment: What happens if you run `/bin/ls` directly?  It's very likely that you have an alias or function in your shell that's making it try to get file stats.  The `*` at the end of `f1` makes me think there's the `-F` flag

Comment: @StephenHarris Yeah that's the reason. problem solved. you guys are amazing.

Comment: Yes, I assume that your `ls` is an alias and uses the `-F` flag to classify the filles, see `ls`(1).  This would try to access `f1` in order to classify it and append an asterisk.  Using `ls --color=no` only appends to the alias.  Try `command ls` instead.  I'm using ArchLinux, should not make a difference.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'm gonna try to understand `command` :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect `ls` in your case is an alias to something like `ls --color=auto`; in that case, `ls` tries to find information about the files contained inside the directory to determine which colour to use.

```
ls --color=no
```

should list the directory without complaining.

If it still complains, then you may be using another option, like `-F` or `--classify`, that needs to access file metadata (`-F`/`--classify` looks at the file type, for example).

To be sure that you run `ls` without going through an alias, use either of

```
command ls
```

or

```
\ls
```

To remove an alias for `ls`, use

```
unalias ls
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just tried `ls --color=no`, but the result is exactly the same.  I also checked `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, and there are no such aliases. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DavidChen What does `type ls` return?

Comment: @Kusalananda `ls is alias of「ls --color -F」` I guess `-F` here is the reason why I still get return code as 1 even using `--clor=no`?

Comment: @DavidChen Yes, that option needs to access the filetype of each file.

Comment: @Kusalananda I know this is kind of unrelated to the original question, but where can the alias be defined other than `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @DavidChen `/etc/profile` or in a file under `/etc/profile.d`?

Comment: @Kusalananda No luck. I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work), and it seems pretty hard to trace where an alias is defined. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Kusalananda It might be worth noting that `unalias ls` is only effective in the current shell life cycle. I'm not sure about the terms, but I mean if you close the terminal and ssh again, the aliases will come into play again.

Comment: @DavidChen Not if you put it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: I believe `'ls'` or `"ls"` (putting the command in quotes) will also bypass the alias, while `/bin/ls` will run an external `ls` utility and ignore any bash-specific features.

Comment: Replacing `-F` with `--file-type` (which will work the same except for appending an `*` to executables) will also prevent `ls` from calling stat(2) on entries. `ls` is using the `d_type` field from the [dirent](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) struct. (that works on most file systems -- minixfs being a notable exception). The only need for that stat() call is to tell apart the executables by looking at their permissions.