# openbsd file permissions for new user

Tags: permissions, openbsd

I'm trying to learn the basics of OpenBSD coming from CentOS ...

so I've created a new certificate for my `domain.tld` with `certbot` and a new user - `newuser`

I've added `newuser` to wheel group and even `chmod -R 777 /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/` but still can't `ls` that directory.

```bash
bsd0# doas -u newuser ls -hasl /etc/letsencrypt/live 
doas (root@bsd0.my.domain) password: 
ls: .: Permission denied
ls: ..: Permission denied
ls: README: Permission denied
ls: domain.tld: Permission denied
total 0
```

Obviously, I'm missing something, but can't figure out what.

Can you help ?

Comment: What are the permissions on the `/etc/letsencrypt/live` and `/etc/letsencrypt` directories?

Comment: Does this solve your issue? [Why can't I access this lets-encrypt certificate file, even though I've set up the group?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423266)

Comment: ```sh
4 drw-rw-rw-   3 root  wheel   512B May 29 15:50 live
```



```sh
4 drwxr-x---   9 root  wheel      512B May 29 15:50 letsencrypt
```

Comment: So it seems as if the user may lack the needed `x` permissions on the intermediate parent directories. I believe the issue is a duplicate of the question I linked to in my second comment above.  Note that this is not OpenBSD-specific but the way Unix permissions on directories work in general.