# User can delete file with read permission only

Tags: permissions, users, group

I created user `small`, added him to group `kek` and allowed that group to only read files in user home directory. Then I chowned all files to `root:kek`. 
However, `small` still can delete files in his home directory.

Commands I ran:

```
useradd -ms /bin/bash small
groupadd kek
usermod -a -G kek small
chown -R root:kek /home/small/*
chmod -R g=r  /home/small/*
```

Then when I try to remove file:

```
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kek  240 Jun 23 06:17 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kek   39 Jun 21 09:17 flag.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kek 2336 Jun 22 14:19 server.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kek   24 Jun 22 08:16 small.py

$ rm flag.txt

$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kek  240 Jun 23 06:17 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kek 2336 Jun 22 14:19 server.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root kek   24 Jun 22 08:16 small.py

$ whoami
small
```

Why does this happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether a file can be deleted or not is not a property of the file but of the directory that the file is located in.  A user may not delete a file that is located in a directory that they can't write to.

Files (and subdirectories) are entries in the directory node. To delete a file, one unlinks it from the directory node and therefore one has to have write permissions to the directory to delete a file in it.

- The write permissions on a file determines whether one is allowed to change the contents of the file.
- The write permissions on a directory determines whether one is allowed to change the contents of the directory.

Related:

- [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251)

Comment: Small question: now I created directory `/home/small/server`, put all files there and `chown` and `chmod` the same way as before. Now `small` cannot chdir to that directory even though group `kek` has read permission, why?

Comment: Why is execute permission needed?

Comment: @nikrom3000 [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

Comment: @nikrom3000 To `cd` into a directory, the user must have execute permissions on it. Read permissions only gives you the ability to list files.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix you do not delete a file, you remove it from a directory listing.
When a file no-longer has any directory listings (it can have many), and is no-longer open by a process, then it will be deleted.

If you have write permission on a directory, then you can remove a files directory listing.

## What to do about it

- Option 1 Remove write permission from the directory.
- Option 2 Add the sticky bit to the directory (`chmod +t «directory-name»`). Make it so that only the owner and root (actually has capability CAP_FOWNER) can remove a file. Use this when you need the write permission, so that user can add files.