No ability to delete files on sftp mounted by sshfs
I mounted sftp dir via sshfs like:
cat <sensitive_data> | sshfs -o password_stdin,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=0,gid=0 $USER@$HOSTNAME: $MOUNT_DIR -oauto_cache,reconnect

And the problem is that I can't delete files on $MOUNT_DIR, despite they have full permission and root as owner, e.g.:
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10505331 Aug 22 14:50 some_file.zip

Wondering if it's at all not available when mounting sftp or it's related with the flags used on sshfs.

This maybe? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451427/108618

@KamilMaciorowski thanks, but looks like I need an other option, parent directory has full access too: drwxrwxrwx

Do the user you ssh as have the appropriate permission on the remote system?

By specifically mointing the volume with the uid=0,gid=0 [root, root] options, you have assigned ownership to root.
Replace the values with the results of id -u;id -g, and your life will be easier.
cat <sensitive_data> | sshfs -o password_stdin,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) $USER@$HOSTNAME: $MOUNT_DIR -oauto_cache,reconnect


Unfortunately it didn't work, still getting: rm: cannot remove 'some_file.zip': Permission denied
