# Setting directory permission to 0570

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

There was an answer to "[Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)" regarding setting a directory permission to 5 (-R-X) value.  It was said it "5: Allow reading / writing, but not altering the structure of the directory tree itself."

If I set my newly created test folder to 0570 I get the following:

```
dr-x-rwx---. user user test1
[user@server1 test1] touch file1
touch: cannot touch 'file1': Permission denied
```

Now the 'user' account is in the 'user' group so I figured if I have rwx perms as user group I could write files still.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Note the `.` at the end of your permissions string indicates that there are additional SELinux permission restrictions applied.  Try `ls -lZ` to dump full permissions.

Comment: I fail to see the "request for learning materials" here. How the user and group permissions interact seems like a valid question to me. (I wouldn't be surprised if there's a duplicate, but surely it can't be off-topic.)

Answer (score 2):

Permissions are evaluated in order by (1) user, (2) group, and (3) other, and only the first match applies.  In this case, the 'user' test matches – you are the owner of the directory.  The permissions on the directory do not allow the user to write to it.

Comment: Thanks Andy, it looks like that if you are a member of a group that has rwx perms and not the owner of the dir then you will be able to write files to that dir.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  In that case, the 'user' test does not match, but the 'group' test does, and the permission on the directory allow members of the group to write to it.