# Can chmod on a directory without --recursive change who can read a file within that directory?

Tags: filesystems, chmod, gnu

Based on the suggested duplicate, let me reformulate my question:

If `chmod 0660 path/to/folder` is run, and user A isn't in the relevant group, could user A still read `/path/to/folder/file.txt` if that file has the appropriate octal?

Comment: Renu, oh dear, I picked the wrong question on the duplicate... I meant this one: [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/170373) That's the one I was reading all along. My bad.

Comment: @ilkkachu - I switched it, thanks for catching this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `/path/to/dir` has the permission bits `0660`, then no-one can access `/path/to/dir/file.txt`, since no-one has the `x` permission on the directory `dir`. (In general, they can't even see the type, size or permission bits of `file.txt`, but some filesystems may reveal some of that data.) The owning user and members of the owning group can list the directory contents (the files within), since they have the `r` permission. The `w` permission isn't really useful without the permission.

See [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/170373)