# How permissions on directories work?

Tags: linux, files

I don't understand how permissions on directories work.
For example:

`r`: I can list all present files in a directory (e.g. `ls`)

`w`: I can modify a file in a directory, delete it and create a new sub-directory

`x`: I can access to a directory (e.g. `cd`)

If I'm right in the following situation:

```
-w-
```

- Can I remove a file if I already know its name?
- Can I remove a file even if I don't have write permissions to it?

Another question. In case of sticky bit (e.g. `/tmp`) I can't remove or rename a file if I'm not its owner: in order to do it a file permission isn't enough?

Comment: If you, for a moment, imagine that a directory is a file whose content is the list of files in it, it helps to explain the permissions on the directory: `r` and you can read the content of the "file" which is the file of files in directory, `w` and you can modify the list of files in the directory, that is deleting or creating new ones, `x` and here the metaphor breaks a little... so no good analogy.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` permission on directory `dir` lets you access the files `dir/file`. Without it, the `w` permission doesn't help you at all, since to create or delete the files, you'd need to be able to point to them.

If you had `-wx` on the directory, however, then you could remove files if you knew their names (and create new files).

Reading the directory, i.e. listing the contents doesn't require accessing any of `dir/file`, just `dir` itself, so if you have `r--`, you can get a listing of the files.

The permissions of the file don't influence removing the file, not even in sticky directories, at least on my Linux. The man page ([chmod(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html)) says you need to be the owner of the file, or the directory to remove or rename files from a sticky directory.

```
/tmp$ ls -l test
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Aug 19 16:17 test
/tmp$ rm test
rm: cannot remove 'test': Operation not permitted
```

See also: [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/170373)

Comment: A `w` permission (without `x`) is totally useless for a directory, right? The `-wx` condition lets me able to remove/rename/add a file, but I'm not able to modify a file (e.g. write something into it) if I don't have the write permission to that file: right? About the sticky bit: if I have a file in `/tmp` like `rwxrwx--- user1 group1` and I'm `user2 group1`, can I remove that file?

Comment: @DrewBer, 1) yep, `w` without `x` is useless as far as I know. 2) And yep, modifying the file is controlled by the file's permissions. 3) I didn't test, but I don't think group membership is enough to delete files from sticky directories. It's not uncommon for a system to have just a single group (say, `users`) for almost all the users, and the point of stickiness would be mostly defeated if members of the group could delete the files of other members of the group.

Comment: I'm thinking about the following case

`drwxr-xrwx    root  root dir`
`-rwxr-xr-x user1 user1 file`

File is inside dir. In the above situation user1 can modify the file due to its write access, but another no-root user can do it due to write access to directory:

1. user2 can remove file
2. user2 can write a modified version of file.

The result is the same, right?

Comment: Considering another case:

`drwxr-x---    root  root dir`
`-rwxr-xr-x user1 user1 file` 

In this case user1 can execute and modify the file but it can't perform ls or cd commands on dir: it can do it if the file path is already known, right?

Last case:

`drwxr-xr--    root  root dir`

user1 can still perform `ls` command on that direcotory without accessing to it, right?

Comment: @DrewBer, that first one is a good point: if you have `w` to `dir`, but not to `dir/file`, you can remove or rename the file and create a new one with the same name. It does change the identity of the file, though: any hard links to it are broken, it could get a new inode, and the new file is owned by the user who re-creates it.

Comment: @DrewBer, in that second one, if you don't have `x` permission to `dir`, then you don't access `dir/file`, period. Not directly with a full pathname, and not through `cd`'ing to the directory first (because you can't do that either)