# Can I set user permissions for a user to read filenames not files

Tags: permissions

How would one, in a unix-based system, give a user read access to the filenames in a folder, but no access to the files themselves?

Answer (score 1):

Just do as you say, set read access on the directory (folder) but not on the files themselves. e.g.

```
umask 022             # others have r-x permissions
mkdir /tmp/f
umask 027             # others have --- permissions
echo hello > /tmp/f/1
ls -la /tmp/f
```

gives

```
total 64
drwxr-xr-x   2 user  user   4096 Feb  5 21:27 .
drwxrwxrwt 370 root root   53248 Feb  5 21:27 ..
-rw-r-----   1 user  user      6 Feb  5 21:27 1
```

Now others can do `ls /tmp/f` and see the `1` file, but can not read it.

Answer (score 0):

With the read (`r`) bit set on the directory you are able to access the filenames of the files inside the directory, 
but you won't be able to access the files or `cd` into that directory unless the execute (`x`) permission is also set on the directory.

In other words: Revoke the write and execute bit on those directories (at least `chmod o=r dirname`).

Related:

- [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)