# Linux - Why do i need to use sudo to read a file, although permission for others is set to read

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo

Based on the permission given below others can also read the file. I am logged in as ec2-user but I have to use sudo to read the file. Since permission is given for everyone to read why does it still ask sudo.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-53-76 ~]$ sudo ls -la /var/log/nginx/access.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nginx root 22731 Sep  2 23:55 /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

permission of each of the folders

```
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root  269 Aug 26 00:52 var
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Sep  3 03:19 log
drwxrwxr--  2 nginx root 159 Sep  3 03:19 nginx
```

What would I have to do so that I can run `tail -n 10 /var/log/nginx/access.log` without having to use `sudo`.

Comment: `drwxrwxr--` no `x` permission on directory for others, so you can't enter that directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

Answer (score 0):

As Muru suggested, you only need `chmod o+x /var/log/nginx` and you should be able to `tail` the file using any user. If you want just a certain user to be able to access it, you can use ACLs.