# Where is the "List files only" Nautilus' permission on terminal?

Tags: command-line, permissions, nautilus

I found out that some folders may have the "List files only" permission on Nautilus. Others have "Access files". Both folders show the same on terminal, using `ls -l` command:

```
drwxr--r--    ...other info...
```

I know what the `drwxr--r--` part means, and I know that the "List files only" permission is not there.

So, where in the terminal can I see (or set) this different permission? Or the "List files only" are stored somewhere else? In this case, where?

I'm using Debian 11.3, Gnome 3.38.5 and Nautilus (Files) 3.38.2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

Comment: `r` for a directory is for listing directory entries, and `x` is for traversing that directory to access something in it.