# tar extract as a specified user : tar: /home/administrateur/glpi-10.0.3.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied

Tags: sudo, tar

Cannot extract tar archive as `www-data` user, I get a `Cannot open: Permission denied` error :

```bash
$ mkdir $HOME/tmp
$ sudo chown www-data $HOME/tmp
$ ll -d $HOME/tmp
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data administrateur 4096 2022-11-10 09:43:14 /home/administrateur/tmp/
$ ll $HOME/glpi-10.0.3.tar
-rwxrwxrwx 1 administrateur administrateur 216893440 2022-09-14 14:28:21 glpi-10.0.3.tar*
$ sudo -u www-data tar -C $HOME/tmp/ -xf $HOME/glpi-10.0.3.tar
tar: /home/administrateur/glpi-10.0.3.tar: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
$
```

EDIT0: Thanks to @Sotto-Voce, the answer is confirmed by this command :

```bash
$ sudo -u www-data test -r $HOME/glpi-10.0.3.tar
$ echo $?
1
$ sudo -u www-data test -r /tmp/glpi-10.0.3.tar
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Does the user `www-data` have permission to read the home directory for the user `administrateur`?

Comment: `r`ead, but more importantly "e`x`ecute", which [for directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/108618) means "access". What is the output of `ls -ld /home/administrateur`?

Comment: @kamil-maciorowski You're right, `www-data` can't read my home dir : `drwxr-x--- 11 administrateur administrateur 4096 Nov 10 10:02 /home/administrateur/
`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski in this question's scenario, execute permissions can substitute for missing read permissions on a directory, but execute isn't more `important` than read.  Execute is more of an `alternative` to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't extract as www-data. As you see, that user has no access to the place you want to extract into, so the operation fails. Instead of trying to extract as a specific user, either extract directly into wherever you want to finally store this (presumably it is not supposed to live in `~/tmp`) or extract as your regular user and then chown the files:

```
$ tar -C "$HOME"/tmp/ -xf "$HOME"/glpi-10.0.3.tar
$ sudo -R chown www-data "$HOME"/tmp/
```