# A question about permissions of hierarchical directories

Tags: permissions, users, directory

I have some directories, with following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 18 user1 root 4096 Oct 27 11:25 /home/test1/test2
drwxr-xr-x 24 user1 root 4096 Oct 21 08:38 /home/test1
drwxr-xr-x 492 root root 12288 Nov 17 01:31 /home
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Nov  6 18:46 /
```

My question:

If I understand right, permission of `/home` says that only root can add/delete files (or directories) in this directory, but then there's the directory `test1` which has `user1` as its owner. That means that user `user1` can add/delete files (or directories) in `/home/test1`. Does this mean that directory permission of `/home` is only valid till its immediate children and not its all descendants (grandchildren and so on)?

And it must be only root who let `user1` be the owner of its child `/home/test1` and from then on, `user1` can control owners of its children (and all descendants)?

Comment: p2pnode, please [learn how to use formatting while asking questions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and use it. Most of your posts engage editors.

Comment: Closely related: [Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13858) Also of interest: [Why do directories need the executable (X) permission to be opened?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251) [In Linux, "Write" Permission Is Equivalent To "Execute" For Directories?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18095)

Answer (score 4):

> Does this mean that directory permission of `/home` is only valid till its immediate children and not its all descendants (grandchildren and so on)?

Only partially.

If you were to change the permissions on `/home` from `drwxr-xr-x` to `drwxr-x---` then user1 would no longer be able to access any files or directories below this.

Go make some files and try it out for yourself.

Comment: `r--` would prevent access, but not `--x`. This distinction is rarely useful anyway. See [In Linux, "Write" Permission Is Equivalent To "Execute" For Directories?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18095)

Comment: [root@dev base]# chmod o-x test
[root@dev base]# exit
exit
[colinm@dev base]$ ls -ld test
drwxrwxr-- 2 root root 4096 Nov 18 12:23 test
[colinm@dev base]$ ls -l test
total 0
?--------- ? ? ? ?            ? test/afile
[colinm@dev base]$ cd test
-bash: cd: test: Permission denied
[colinm@dev base]$ cat test/afile
cat: test/afile: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

The directory permission of home is only valid for itself.  Once user1 has permissions on a directory it can do anything, including create subdirectories.  So, once there is a directory under home that user1 has permissions on, it user1 can add anything to that directory.

However, if a directory under user1 was to be owned by another user, then user1 would only have world permissions on that directory.