# Can I share a folder inside my home directory with another user?

Tags: permissions, directory, group

Can I share a folder inside my home directory with another user?

I have two users on a system, `agent` and `daemon`. An external server connects as `agent` and rsyncs files to `~agent/incoming`

I want `daemon` to have access to the files in `~agent/incoming` but I don't want `agent` to have access to any of `daemon`'s files.

I set up a group called `automaton` and added both users to it. I then chmod'ed the `~agent/incoming` folder to `drwxrws---` (notice the sticky bit) and chowned that folder to `agent:automaton`.

The process runs and new files are delivered to the `incoming` folder and are set as `agent:automaton` with permissions `-rw-rw----` but `daemon` is not able to view or copy these files:

```
stat: cannot stat (path here) : Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is difficult to answer precisely because you haven't said what path you're passing to the daemon and you haven't specified the permissions of `~agent`. If you start the daemon in the `~agent/incoming` directory and pass it relative paths, then since the daemon is in the `automaton` group it will be able to read, write and delete the files in the `~agent/incoming` directory.

I guess what's happening is:

1. The `~agent` directory is not executable to the daemon.
2. The path passed to the daemon includes `~agent` as a component (say, it's an absolute path).

When a process accesses `/home/agent/incoming/foo`, it must have execution permissions on all the directories that are traversed: `/`, `/home`, `/home/agent` and `/home/agent/incoming` (more if some of these are symbolic links).

If the daemon accesses `foo` while its current directory is `~agent/incoming`, it only needs to have execution permissions on the current directory (`~agent/incoming`) itself. You need to manage to make that directory current; `chdir` requires that the process have access to the target directory. This is possible if you first change to the desired directory while running as (say) the `agent` user, then run something like `su daemon -c daemon-command`.

Comment: thanks, just needed to g+x the user's home directory. not sure if that is the best thing to do securely, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

there is no permission for daemon in '~agent/' folder eventhough he has permission for '~agent/incoming' so it is hierarchy of permissions see this [A question about permissions of hierarchical directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24792/a-question-about-permissions-of-hierarchical-directories)