# Is there any useful purpose for directories with permissions -w-?

Tags: permissions, directory

Being aware of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136864/64248) I wonder whether there is any useful purpose for write-only directories, i.e. directories with permissions `-w-`.

Any directory-"writing" operation I know of (such as `creat`, `mkdir`, `link`, `unlink`, `symlink`, `rename`) fails with permissions `-w-` but works perfectly with permissions `-wx`.

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate. I've seen that question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any usage except `d-w--w--w-` looks nicer than `d---------`, you can use it if you want to protect a directory from modifications.

(just joking here)