# Why are execute permissions required to rename files in a directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, mv

Say I'm the owner of a directory and I have read and write permissions, but not execute permissions, where the directory structure is like this:

```
x/           (drw-r--r--)
    y        (-rw-r--r--)
    z        (-rw-r--r--)
```

I know that without execute permissions, I can't `cd` to the directory, but I thought that renaming files within the directory would count as "writing" to the directory. Thus it surprised me that the following command gave a permission denied.

```
mv x/y x/w
```

Why does `mv` require execute permissions on the directory `x`? Is it something special about the `mv` command? Is `mv` using `cd` internally or something?

Comment: Yes, `mv` [requires execute permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20949131/2089697) on the directory `x`.

Comment: @Harvinder Do you know *why* this is the case?

Answer (score 4):

After looking at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18098/67823) to a related question, I think I understand.

A directory is a list of files, and "executing" that directory means following the links in the directory list to the files themselves. Thus, since I don't have execute permissions on `x`, I can't resolve the path `x/y` to the actual file `y` in the command `mv x/y x/w`. (In order to get the actual file `y`, the directory entry for `y` in `x` has to be followed, which is part of what "executing" `x` means.)

However, if we give the user execute but not write permissions on `x`, then we can copy a file from within `x` to outside `x`, like so:

```
chmod u+x-w x
cp x/y y
```