# Can't open file even though directory/file is owned by user and in group

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chmod

I am having a really tough time understand user/group permissions.  I have spent hours reading and trying things.  Here is what I have:

**Directories Permissions**

Input 1: `ls -lhd`

Output 1:

/var/log: `drwxrwxr-x 11 root syslog 4.0K May 10 01:59 .`

/var/log/mongosqld: `drw-rw-r-- 2 mongosqld logstash 4.0K May 10 03:37 .`

Note: I set this up using `chown` and `chgrp`.

**File Permissions**

Input 2: `ls -lh`

Output 2:

/var/log/mongosqld:

```
total 12K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mongosqld logstash 1.4K May 10 03:43 mongosqld.log
```

**Groups:**

Input: `groups logstash mongosqld`

Output:

```
logstash : logstash
mongosqld : users logstash
```

**My Question**

When I try to open a file as the `mongosqld` user, it tells me `open /var/log/mongosqld/mongosqld.log: permission denied`.  Where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t access *anything* in `/var/log/mongosqld`
(unless you’re running as root)
because it (the directory) doesn’t have any e**x**ecute bits set.

Comment: Hello @Scott.  I ran `sudo chmod +x /var/log/mongosqld/`, and the case is closed!  I am wondering, do you know why open requires execute?  In my mind, that is a write permissions kind of thing.

Comment: Our main resource on that is [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/23408) See also [Confused about the “execute” bit of a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/409597/23408) for some additional answers.