# New user can't access their home

Tags: linux, permissions

So I'm adding a new user on a machine to give a family member some remote storage. After setting up their login and home directory. Here's the stat

```
  File: `/home/heather'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 831h/2097d  Inode: 89128961    Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1002/ heather)   Gid: ( 1004/ heather)
Access: 2014-09-09 17:57:37.059406231 -0400
Modify: 2014-09-09 17:37:32.449432887 -0400
Change: 2014-09-09 17:57:22.939336208 -0400
```

But they are not able to access it from either local or ssh

```
$ echo ~
/home/heather
$ cd ~
bash: cd: /home/heather: Permission denied
```

Unless I'm missing something big, the permissions seem fine.

Please note I've only ever run single-user setups before, I can't find anything similar to this after a good 20 minutes of searching, please don't crucify me if I've overlooked something simple.

Comment: What is the output of `finger heather` command?

Comment: Login: heather           Name: 
Directory: /home/heather             Shell: /bin/bash
Last login Tue Sep  9 18:45 (EDT) on pts/10 from [snip]
No mail.
No Plan.

Comment: What are the permissions on /home?

Comment: I believe the execute permission might not be set which is causing the issue. So probably, do a `chmod -R 755 /home/heather` as a root user and then try again.

Comment: sorry for delay, permission of /home are `Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/  andrew)   Gid: ( 1000/  andrew)`, i think this is the issue, not sure how best to fix

Comment: `chmod 755 /home` should fix this.

Comment: Wow, i'm really off my game today, how didn't i think of that. thanks.

Comment: @Warwick Yes -  do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `chmod 755 /home` and this should be fixed. Gilles answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13891/72876) is worth looking at for a full explanation of this.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX  knows effective users/group with uid/gui not name. So check id and gid of your home directory.

```
   stat --printf=%u /home/heather  #####print uid of your home dir 
   stat --printf=%g /home/heather  #####print gid of your home dir
```

Then check with `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` :

```
egrep heather /etc/passwd
egrep heather /etc/groups
```