# A password is not necessary to enter my /home directory but after logging out password is necessary

Tags: opensuse, password, access-control

I have an opensuse 42.1 leap Linux. I deleted my /home folder accidentally from my other linux which is Debian.
For some reason I had to transfer everything from my /home directory to a new partition. Then, everything is fine except that I do not need any password to enter my /home directory now. But when I am logging out and trying to enter my home directory I need a password.

Why do I not need a password to enter ?

Comment: What do you need the password for cq what program prompts you? Is this the general bootup login, that was previously not necessary or some other program. Who is the owner of the homedirectory? Make sure you are the owner if this all has been restored from some remote computer.

Comment: Sounds like an ownership issue, I would probably do something like **chown -R username /home/username/** which I think would change the ownership of the home directory and all subdirectories and files to "username". (Using chown on such a large scale is usually a bad idea, but the point of your home directory is pretty much that you should have complete control over all the files in it)

If that doesn't do the trick, read up on **chmod**.

Comment: The problem is not solved. I tried everything you suggested. It did not change anything

Answer (score 0):

The likely problems:

- you do not own the actual home directory (or shell initialization files)
- you did not adjust the location of the home directory in `/etc/passwd` after moving it.

Further reading:

- [Command to change the default home directory of a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797819/command-to-change-the-default-home-directory-of-a-user)
- [New user can't access their home](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154691/new-user-cant-access-their-home)
- [usermod - modify a user account](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) (the `-d` option specifies the directory)

Comment: The problem still is not solved. The same problem persists.

Comment: I think  I need to "adjust the location of the home directory in /etc/passwd" . But how?...