# Noip “Can't locate configuration file”, but the file is there

Tags: files, permissions

I installed Noip and ran the command which created the config file

```
/usr/local/bin/noip2 -C
```

and then I ran the run command

```
/usr/local/bin/noip2
```

and it returned

```
Can't locate configuration file /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf. (Try -c). Ending!
```

I checked the location of the file and it was definitely there.
Any idea why it could not locate the file?

Output of strace:

```
execve("/usr/local/bin/noip2", ["/usr/local/bin/noip2"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1375000
uname({sys="Linux", node="raspberrypi", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f33000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 44, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f32000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\270\4\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 7276, SEEK_SET)                = 7276
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1080) = 1080
lseek(3, 7001, SEEK_SET)                = 7001
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=10170, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 39740, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6f07000
mprotect(0xb6f09000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6f10000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1) = 0xb6f10000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb6f32000, 44)                  = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=44950, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 44950, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xb6efc000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\214y\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
lseek(3, 1198880, SEEK_SET)             = 1198880
read(3, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 1360) = 1360
lseek(3, 1198444, SEEK_SET)             = 1198444
read(3, "A.\0\0\0aeabi\0\1$\0\0\0\0056\0\6\6\10\1\t\1\n\2\22\4\24\1\25"..., 47) = 47
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1200240, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 1242408, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xb6dcc000
mprotect(0xb6eef000, 28672, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xb6ef6000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x122) = 0xb6ef6000
mmap2(0xb6ef9000, 9512, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6ef9000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f32000
set_tls(0xb6f324c0, 0xb6f32b98, 0xb6f37048, 0xb6f324c0, 0xb6f37048) = 0
mprotect(0xb6ef6000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xb6f36000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xb6efc000, 44950)               = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {SIG_IGN, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, {SIG_IGN, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, {SIG_IGN, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {0xa568, [], 0x4000000 /* SA_??? */}, NULL, 8) = 0
getcwd("/home/pi", 4096)                = 9
lstat64("/home/pi/noip2", 0xbef6f670)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(2, "Can't locate configuration file "..., 79Can't locate configuration file /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf. (Try -c). Ending!

) = 79
exit_group(-1)                          = ?
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the output of `strace /usr/local/bin/noip2`

Comment: edited with strace output

Comment: It exists but the user pi cannot read the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open("/usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

`noip2` tries to open its configuration file for reading and writing, and when this fails it tries again just to read, which also fails. The failure is due to a lack of permission; the error message is unhelpfully generic.

Check the permissions of the configuration file and of the directories leading to it (well, `/` and `/usr` are surely ok, or your system would be broken in more visible ways).

```
ls -ld /usr/local /usr/local/etc /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf
```

The directories must have at least the `x` permission bit for the user running the command — probably for all users. The file itself must have at least the `r` permission bit. The directories should have the `r` permission bit (strictly speaking, it isn't required, but it's the normal thing; see [Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory/13891#13891) for details).

You probably want `chmod a+rX /usr/local/etc /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf`, unless the configuration file is supposed to be confidential (e.g. because it contains a password).

If one of the entries has `+` after the `r`/`w`/`x` permission bits, then there is a security framework such as SELinux which may be imposing additional restrictions.

Comment: Thanks! The ls command came up with -rw------- so I ran the chmod which changed the permissions to -rw-r--r-- so I modified the command slightly to make it -rwxr-xr-x. Thanks for helping me to learn about chmod in the process!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  I think it was a permissions issue.  It worked for me to run it as root:

```
$ sudo noip2
```

You might have to kill running instances first.

```
$ ps -A |grep noip
 1577 ?        00:00:00 noip2
$ sudo kill 1577
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a permissions problem.  I fixed with:

```
chown noip.wheel /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf
```

Comment: What is the name of the user in general terms?

Answer (score 0):

Mine was RO file system, strace show
`, O_RDWR) = -1 EROFS (Read-only file system)`

Copy to /dev/shm helps :D