# How do I debug filesystem permissions?

Tags: permissions, debugging

I get permission errors when I have a process running as root, spawning a subprocess as www-data, which then accesses a dir which is owned by root, with a subfolder which is owned by www-data, which has a *symlink* to a dir which is owned by a user in the group www-data, which then has.... you get the idea.

How the heck do I know where it fails in this impossibly complex chain? All I get is **Permission Denied**

Without getting bogged down in the details of this particular situation, how does one begin to debug a problem like this on Unix?

I want to just say

```
debug_permissions.sh www-data /my/long/symlink/chain
```

and I want it to go through the symlink chain and tell me where the terminal point is (where www-data fails to have permissions).

I know there is a [tool](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/namei.1.html)

```
namei -l /path/
```

but that isn't very helpful because it doesn't let me run as another user (or at least I don't know how).

If I run `sudo su www-data`, I get **This account is currently not available.**

I want to be able to "become" www-data and `cd` around to the dirs and see where I fail to see things. But that's not letting me do this and I don't want to create a new user just to do this.

Answer (score 9):

Aha, this does it:

```
sudo -H -u www-data namei /my/long/symlink/chain
```

where `www-data` is the user I'm trying to debug

Comment: Strictly speaking that is the answer how to solve your particular problem, not how to debug permissions... (I'd have used `strace` for that to find the call that actually gives problems).

Comment: Please post an example of how to use strace -- I have never used it

Comment: E.g. [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/strace-examples/), or [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=strace+examples) for lots more.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I have a couple of tactics to debug file system permission issues.

Assuming that an example user named `userWhoShouldHaveAccess` is supposed to be able to list the contents of the directory `/dir/with/access/issues`, I'll have this running in a terminal to learn whether whatever I tried worked:

```
watch sudo -u userWhoShouldHaveAccess ls /dir/with/access/issues
```

The following lets me keep an eye on the permissions from the root directory to the directory I want the user to access:

```
cd / && watch namei -l /dir/with/access/issues
```

I'll keep in mind that in order to list files in a directory, the user must traverse the whole path `/dir/with/access/issues`, meaning the user must have executable permissions in the target directory [*and all the parent directories*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory/13891#13891).

I'll keep in mind that group changes to a user are only effective after logging out and logging in again, although there are [workarounds](https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out) for that.

I can show the user ID and the groups the user belongs to with `id userWhoShouldHaveAccess`.

Since there are also [access control lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access-control_list) in addition to the owner/group/other permissions that determine access, I'll check those with

```
getfacl /dir/with/access/issues
```

If the user should be able to write, I can run this in the background to learn when writing works:

```
while true; do sudo -u userWhoShouldHaveAccess bash -c '(echo "Test at $(date) by $(whoami)" >> /dir/with/access/issues/test_file);sleep 1';done
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work) are some basics of file permissions on Linux.