# Permissions folder/parent folder

Tags: permissions, shared-folders

I have a doubt concerning the permissions of folders in my operating system course.

Imagine that an ubuntu OS has three users : Lee, Xon, Yugi.

Lee creates a parent folder X, and gives full permissions (rwx) to Xon, but gives (---) permissions to Yugi. Xon goes in X and creates a new folder called Y ,and he gives full permissions (rwx) to Yugi on that folder.

Since Yugi does not have permission on X would he be able to make use of his permission on Y ? (Knowing that a user must have permissions for the entire path to access a folder)

Comment: No yugi would not!

Comment: Look here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858/do-the-parent-directorys-permissions-matter-when-accessing-a-subdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Yugi would not as he can't even get past `X` to get to `Y`. The lack of execution permission on `X` for Yugi means he can't even do `cd` into `X` to access `Y`