# Why do have some directories like /var/lib/{docker,sudo} 0711 rights?

Tags: debian, filesystems

I've noticed that the directories `/var/lib/{docker,sudo}` have `0711` rights (`rwx--x--x`) by default. Is this some kind of mistake, or why grant someone the right to enter a directory `x`, without being able to read `r` it's contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be useful if subdirectories of `/var/lib/{docker,sudo}` (not necessarily first-level subdirectories) need to be accessible to other users. To visit any directory, you need to have access permission on all its parents. (See [Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13858/86440))