# One folder - multiple user permission

Tags: permissions

I created folder `/home/john/Desktop/test`. 
I want to give it access to user `john` itself and to user `mike`.

I created group:

```
sudo groupadd jm
```

And added users to same group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G jm john
sudo usermod -a -G jm mike
```

Then gave right:

```
sudo chgrp -R jm /home/john/Desktop/test
sudo chmod -R 770 /home/john/Desktop/test
```

When I login with `mike` and write `cd /home/john/Desktop/test` ,
it writes `Permission denied`.

What may be the problem?

Output of ls -la:

```
drwxrwx---+ 2 john jm 4096 Nov 7 15:35 test
```

Comment: Does Mike have access to John's home directory and the `Desktop` directory?  The `jm` group (or "others") needs at least `x` permissions on all intermediate directories between `/` and `/home/john/Desktop/test`.

Comment: No, Mike does not have access to John's home and Desktop directory. How to give access to Mike to that folders?

Comment: `chmod o+x /home/john /home/john/Desktop` or (but you probably don't want this) `chgrp jm /home/john /home/john/Desktop` followed by `chmod g+x /home/john /home/john/Desktop`.

Comment: thank you @Kusalananda. So it means it is better to create directory in the root (/) of linux and give access to other users.

Comment: Well, no matter where you create it, all users that should have access to it needs to also have at least `x` access to all the directories above it.

Comment: @Kusalananda, very clear! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarise the discussions in the comments below the question itself:

For a user to have access to a directory, the user also has to have at least execute permissions on all directories above that directory, and on the directory itself.  This may be achieved through either of the user, group or "other" permission bits.

For user `mike` to have access to the directory `/home/john/Desktop/test`, the user must therefore have `x` permissions on all of the directories

- `/`,
- `/home`,
- `/home/john`,
- `/home/john/Desktop`, and on
- `/home/john/Desktop/test`.

If the user is not the owner of a directory in this list, they must be part of a group that has `x` permissions on it, or the directory must have `x` permissions set for "others".

Related:

- [Do the parent directory's permissions matter when accessing a subdirectory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13858)
- [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251)