# cd into directory throws "permission error". Which directory needs execute permission?

Tags: permissions

Note:  I have read and *think I understand* what's written in [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/execute-vs-read-bit-how-do-directory-permissions-in-linux-work)

But I may be missing **where** in the hierarchy that execute directory permission needs to be set to `cd` into a directory.

Specifically, I am trying to make the postgres log group-readable so that I can look at the execution log.  FWIW, though it's not part of my question, I edited **postgresql.conf** to set `log_file_mode = 0640`.

Note: `PGDATA=/opt/local/var/db/postgresql13/defaultdb`.

so now, let's `cd $PGDATA/log`

Permission error.

OK, `sudo su postgres` then `chmod 750 $PGDATA/log`

I have now set the execute bit on the log directory.

`cd $PGDATA/log`

Permission error.

Turned out that I needed to set the execute on the parent of $PGDATA/log, i.e. `chmod 750 $PGDATA` .  Then `cd $PGDATA/log` worked.

I understand the logic behind requiring `x` set on `$PGDATA` if I was doing say `ls $PGDATA` and looking at what is in $PGDATA.  But I never tried to, I was going directly into `$PGDATA/log`.

So, is it correct to say that to `cd <somedir>` you really execute permission on somedir's parent, not just the directory itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One folder - multiple user permission](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480363)

Comment: @Kusalananda it does and so do some of the linked questions there.  Perhaps naive of me, but I had no idea that the whole parent hierarchy needed taking into account.

Comment: Yes, each directory on the path down to wherever is being accessed needs to be accessible.

Comment: As you understand from [the other question](/q/480355/80216), you didn’t understand that the user must have execute permission on *every* directory in a path.  But you got something else wrong: to do `ls "$PGDATA"` and look at the *names* of the things in `$PGDATA`, you need ***read*** permission on `$PGDATA`.  In fact, to do `ls "$PGDATA"` and look at *only* the names of the things in `$PGDATA`, read permission on `$PGDATA` is ***all*** you need.  To do `ls -l "$PGDATA"` and look at the names *and attributes* of the things in `$PGDATA`, you need read and execute permission on `$PGDATA`.